# Deletar linhas duplicadas em uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Utilizei o seguinte SELECT pra encontrar os valores repetidos:

```
SELECT nome, Count(nome) FROM projeto
GROUP BY nome
HAVING Count(nome)>1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora preciso deletar tudo o que está repetido e deixar apenas o primeiro que foi inserido. Estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
DELETE FROM projeto
WHERE nome IN
  (SELECT nome FROM projeto
   GROUP BY nome
   HAVING Count(nome)>1)
AND NOT id_projeto IN
  (SELECT Min(id_projeto) FROM projeto
   GROUP BY nome
   HAVING Count(nome)>1)
```

Porém, estou recebendo o seguinte erro: 
**#1093 - You can't specify target table 'projeto' for update in FROM clause**

Alguma ideia do que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algumas maneira de fazer isso, aquilo que me ocorre de forma simples é algo como:

```
-- Obter apenas um ocorrencia de nome e guardar na temporaria.
select distinct nome into #tmp From projeto

-- Apagar dados originais.
Delete from projeto

-- Voltar a repor os dados na tabela original.
Insert into projeto select * from #tmp
```

Comment: #tmp seria uma variável ou uma tabela temporária?

Comment: Tabela temporária.

Comment: Não consegui resolver, Sérgio. Se pudesse detalhar um pouco mais talvez ficasse um pouco mais claro pra mim.

Comment: Falta mudar o * por Nome, que é ocorrencia a contar.

Comment: Consegui solucionar juntamente com essa pergunta também: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288245/delete-duplicate-rows-in-mysql 
Obrigada, Sérgio!